# Change Target of Edge in BGL

Tags: boost-graph

If my BGL graph contain edge from node x to node y, and I want to change the target of this edge, so that now it's pointing from x to z, how it can be done?

Are there any functions in BGL for that?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove an edge and add another one instead - see `remove_edge` and `add_edge` defined in the [MutableGraph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/graph/doc/MutableGraph.html) concept. I don't see any direct manipulation function. Alternatively, you can define your own one that would hide the removal and addition. Special care should be taken for the graphs with properties attached to edges (i.e. [MutablePropertyGraph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/graph/doc/MutablePropertyGraph.html)).